# Simple HttpResponse in ASPX VB

Tags: asp.net, node.js, vb.net

We have an old Asp.net 2.0 web service where I need to put in a simple HTTP response. In the below code, the function "APIValidation()" returns an int, 200 or 404. All I need to do is have it send an HttpResponse so my node web app can read the statuscode (and then do what it needs to do).

I have no idea how to do this (I'm a noob with ASP), the tutorials I find are too elaborate, it seems this could be solved in a few lines of code, I just don't know which.

You can see it in action here:

200 : http://registration.imprintplus.com/imprinttest/GlobalSrvSN.aspx?sn=29820C0792024CDC8D590BF14AF42490

404: http://registration.imprintplus.com/imprinttest/GlobalSrvSN.aspx?sn=invalid

The other option is for Node to be able to extract the 200 or 404 out of what the ASP service gives me. Either or works for me.

```
Option Explicit Off
Option Strict Off

Imports ActivationServer

Partial Class GlobalSrvSN
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Function APIValidation(ByVal sn As String, ByVal databaseSource As String) As String

        Dim act As New LogicProtect_ActivationServer(databaseSource)


        Return act.APIValidation("user", "user@company.com", sn)

    End Function
End Class
```

thanks a million!

Comment: Where's the call that actually invokes that `function`? I would look at that part to handle the actual http response after obtaining the `string` result from it..Hth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure how you're calling that function so will assume a few things if that's the only code you have.

If you're calling it from the `.aspx` file then this would be an example:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" ....." %>

<%
    Dim foo = APIValidation(Request("sn"), "other string")
    Response.StatusCode = CInt(foo)
%>
```

If from "code behind" (`[page].aspx.vb`):

```
Option Explicit Off
Option Strict Off

Imports ActivationServer

Partial Class GlobalSrvSN
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim foo = APIValidation(Request("sn"), "other string")
        Response.StatusCode = CInt(foo)
    End Sub

    Public Function APIValidation(ByVal sn As String, ByVal databaseSource As String) As String

        Dim act As New LogicProtect_ActivationServer(databaseSource)    
        Return act.APIValidation("user", "user@company.com", sn)

    End Function
End Class
```

Notes: Above is a **very trivial** answer to keep things simple. But:

- above is really a "Web Forms Page" (not technically a "web service") which would be `asmx` (2.0)
- Skipped any input validation (`queryString`), error checking/handling.
- `Response` object is how you'd control HTTP Responses (`headers`, etc.)

Hth

Comment: Hi EdSF,

Looks like I'm almost there, I did need to put it the .aspx file.
I am getting a "BC30545: Property access must assign to the property or use its value." error when using 

Dim foo = APIValidation(Request("sn"), "other string")
Response.StatusCode = CInt(foo)

Not sure what could be wrong there.
thanks for your help!

Comment: Nevermind, got it! 

I mistakenly put Response.StatusCode(foo) instead of Response.StatusCode = foo due to copy-pasting a Response.Write